# uninitialized constant Api::Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, doorkeeper

I have API engine inside my Rails app and I've mounted the engine under in the main app routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Api::Engine => "/api"
end
```

and I want to add the doorkeeper routes using use_doorkeeper function in my routes like this

```
Api::Engine.routes.draw do
  use_doorkeeper :scope => "api/oauth"
end
```

this doesn't work because it tries to find controllers under api/doorkeeper/controller_name instead of doorkeeper/controller_name

as a workaround I've added doorkeeper routes in main app routes.rb with a scope like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Api::Engine => "/api"
  use_doorkeeper :scope => "api/oauth"
end
```

But I want to know if there is a solution so I can still add the routes to api/config/routes.rb and make reference the correct controllers path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my colleague suggested this solution [found here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/328#issuecomment-34019343) and it worked for me :)

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  old_scope = @scope[:module]
  @scope[:module] = nil
  use_doorkeeper
  @scope[:module] = old_scope
end
```